# How to record macro to record find command

Tags: sublimetext

I use ctrl+q to start recording macro in sublime text. I can record macro for copy/paste commands. However I cannot record it for find command. I used command+G to find a text that is already in clipboard.
How can I record the find command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, recording macros for find/replace is still [not possible](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=8761). You might want to take a look at the [RegReplace](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/RegReplace) package though.